# how to make single view with multiple imageviews?

Tags: android, android-layout

**how to make single view with multiple imageviews?**

I know this is just a simple question but its puzzle for me ...

**problem**

there are 4 images one for whole background image ,2nd is transparent heart and 3 image is to put in heart and 4 image is a shadow image of heart but how to manage these four images in a single view(any layout)....
 Any help would be appreciated see link to see my desired output

[link to see photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMRKC.jpg)

**update**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/hv_effect"
    android:layout_below="@+id/effect_hedaer_toolbar"
    android:background="@drawable/home_wall"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:padding="50dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_effect_main"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_effect_bg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/pip" />

    </FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

> i have used relative for background image and framelayout  to show two imageview to show one is for to show lamp image and second two move as background (user selected image)....
>   **problem:**
>   problem is user selected image must be move only inside lamp.

**update read comments to get answer**

Comment: The question is... why do you need 4 images instead of just 1? It's much less performant and more memory consuming.

Comment: @LonnieZamora i just wanna make pip effect like this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.photoeditorapps.pipphotocamera&hl=en  but when i decode this app i got different images ....so i tought that they use different imageview

Comment: @LonnieZamora the image is in heart  and background are selected  by user from gallery and camera  and below there is a shadow image.. now tell me how to manage these all in a single view....

Comment: If they do, it's really a bad practice. Don't passively imitate others. Be smarter. Maybe the background can be a separate image, so to be re-used for other things than the heart itself (and to be choosen as a different one from time to time). But The heart and its shadow should really be one thing

Comment: Anyway, a RelativeLayout or a FrameLayout are your friends.

Comment: use `LayerDrawable`: "A Drawable that manages an array of other Drawables. These are drawn in array order, so the element with the largest index will be drawn on top."

Comment: finally solved see below ans's comment to see ans

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can do it simply by using a RelativeLayout. The transparent image should be the last one in the layout, example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/background_image"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/transparent_image"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Or a FrameLayout, as well.

Comment: if u want to see real app see here https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.photoeditorapps.pipphotocamera&hl=en

Comment: bdw problem solved ..porterImageview,portershapeimageview  classes solved my problem using different images ... https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/github/siyamed/shapeimageview/mask/PorterShapeImageView.java ANd https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/github/siyamed/shapeimageview/mask/PorterImageView.java

Comment: but in porterimageview class i have extend this class https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java